# Double quotes being replaced with ' + CHAR(34) + ' in SQL using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, delphi, delphi.net

I am using SQL Server 2008 Web Edition and it seems my SQL queries are automagically having the double quotes replaced with `' + CHAR(34) + '`. I am trying to pin down why this is happening, I am using Delphi with ASP.NET and using the ADO.NET object for the SQL.

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Do you have a problem because of the replacement or are you just curious to where it happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that it isn't ASP.NET or Delphi causing the issue but is the editor I am using to allow the user to input data. It is replacing all the double quotes before spitting the content out to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try escape them:  `Result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(InputTxt, @"[\000\010\011\012\015\032\042\047\134\140]", "\\$0");`

EDIT: sorry, didn't realize you were using delphi. I'm sure the theory still applies even if the code doesn't.

Comment: I am trying to not to hack it in some way if there is an option I am missing somewhere. No worries about the langauge, I have learned to use C# and VB since moving to ASP.NET, there isn't much resource for ASP.NET in delphi :)